# Find text (ISBN) on page and attach link on it in JS

Tags: firefox, dom

For a browser (Firefox) addon I need to find ISBN's on certain pages (such as: amazon.com, book.com).

I need to find those DOM elemets containing the ISBN and manipulate them with a link, which sends the ISBN to a REST Webservice for further logic.

Since I'm new to JavaScript I don't have any idea how to get into this because the homepages differ in how they display the ISBN.

This is the current implementation:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");

// a dummy function, to show how tests work.
// to see how to test this function, look at test/test-index.js
function dummy(text, callback) {
  callback(text);
}

exports.dummy = dummy;

var tag = "body"
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;


var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  //tabs.open("http://www.mozilla.org/");
  tabs.open("http://www.amazon.com");

}

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("modify-content.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.emit("getElements", tag);
    worker.port.on("gotElement", function(elementContent) {
      console.log(elementContent);
    });
  }
});
```

This is the modify-content.js

```
self.port.on("getElements", function(tag) {

  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    var isbn = elements[i].innerText.match("(ISBN[-]*(1[03])*[ ]*(: ){0,1})*(([0-9Xx][- ]*){13}|([0-9Xx][- ]*){10})");

    if(isbn != undefined){
        //self.port.emit("gotElement", elements[i].innerHTML);
        console.log(isbn);      
    }

    self.port.emit("gotElement", elements[i].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

The ISBN's are found. But how do I manipulate the DOM Element surrounding the ISBN?

Comment: You might want to check out the various ISBN formats https://www.wikiwand.com/en/International_Standard_Book_Number. Also a link that provides a regular expression in various languages https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s13.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware of the various formats. I already got a regex for that. My question was more how to find the DOM element (without knowing the ID or type of it) in a page to give it a link.

Comment: Try : body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText

Comment: I updated the Code for further assistance. As I wrote in the original post, the ISBN's are found but I have no idea how to get the surrounding element for manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're having trouble translating back from a `innerText` regexp match, which is a string, to the *nearest* html element of that match.

The difficult part is that the DOM is a tree. So if a `<div>` has a `<p>` which has a `<span>` which has an ISBN number, all of those elements' `innerText` will contain that ISBN number. We want to reach the "deepest" element that contains a match, ignoring all of its parents.

One (rather expensive, brute-force) way of doing this, is by recursively looping through your elements, layer by layer.

- When there is a match in the `innerText`, we'll look at *every* child element.
- If none of the children has a match, we return the current element because it's the last known DOM element that *had* a match

Other than performance, I think there are still edge cases that won't match. For example, if there's a `<span>` that contains three, comma separated, ISBN numbers. You'll probably have to add one last layer: a layer that creates *new* elements around each individual string.

```js
var isbnRegExp = new RegExp("(ISBN[-]*(1[03])*[ ]*(: ){0,1})*(([0-9Xx][- ]*){13}|([0-9Xx][- ]*){10})");

var start = document.body;

var findDeepestMatch = function(el, regexp, result) {
  result = result || [];

  if (regexp.test(el.innerHTML)) {
    var childMatches = Array.from(el.children)
      .filter(child => regexp.test(child.innerHTML));

    // Case 1: there's a match here, but not in any of the children: return el
    if (childMatches.length === 0) {
      result.push(el);
    } else {
      childMatches.forEach(child => findDeepestMatch(child, regexp, result));
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.time("Find results")
var results = findDeepestMatch(start, isbnRegExp);
console.timeEnd("Find results")

var makeISBN = el => {
  el.classList.add("isbn");
  el.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(el.innerText));
};

results.forEach(makeISBN);
```

```css
.isbn { color: green; border-radius: 3px; background: rgba(0,255,0,0.2); cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Some book: <span>978-0451524935</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        Some nested book: <span><strong>ISBN</strong>-978-0451524935</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        Some phone number: <span>0012-34-5678909</span>  <code><-- regexp problem?</code>
      </li>
      <li>
        Some email: <span>abc@def.gh</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    Here are no isbn numbers
  </div>
  Here's one <a><strong>ISBN</strong>-<em>978</em>-0451524935</a>
</div>
```